# What is the internal buffer size for "fs.createReadStream"

Tags: node.js, stream, buffer, fs

What is the internal buffer size for "fs.createReadStream" ?

From the stream's documentation, it is mentioned that the fs.createReadStream uses an internal buffer that is accessible via `readable._readableState.buffer`

From the stream's documentation, it is mentioned that the default `highWaterMark` is `64kb`.

But the `readable._readableState.buffer.length` get's 1, not 8 (8 bytes = 64 kb). Why is that ?

References:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/stream.html#stream_buffering
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Comment: "8 bytes = 64kb" What?

Comment: @tkausl b refers to bit and B refers to byte right ?

Comment: See https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L90. Internally, it's not a simple single buffer.

Comment: I am getting `0` as `fs.createReadStream('math.js')._readableState.buffer.length` for a nonempty file, I wonder why. See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73386713/1614973